# How can I create .po file using Poedit in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, po

How can I create .po file using Poedit in Ubuntu? It only opens catalog. But, I want to generate .po file of my php file. Any ideas?

Comment: Hope this will help you... Check this link
http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/create-pot-file-using-poedit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your answer:[Localizing your Application with PoEdit](http://circlical.com/blog/2013/11/5/localizing-your-twig-using-zend-framework-2-applications)

Comment: Yes there it gives option of creating po file. But, in ubuntu, there is no option of File->Create Catalog.. I require this..